# Android wear sample app

Tags: android, eclipse, wear-os

I'm trying to understand how it works Android Wear: I installed (after a lot of problems) the library to Eclipse, I connected the Android Phone by cable to the mac in which I will develop and the Emulator is synchronized with the real phone. I tried to send myself a mail to see if the connection work and it works well. Now I will try to do something with this, but where I can find sample code to try and understand how Android Wear works? Did anyone found something to try out this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you signup for the Developer preview on

http://developer.android.com/wear/preview/start.html

you will get sample applications WearableNotificationsSample, ElizaChat sample code.

Then 
import these projects and create a libs/ directory in your project root (the same location as the AndroidManifest.xml file). Copy the v4 support library JAR file from your Android SDK directory (e.g., /extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar) into your project libs/ directory. Also save the wearable-preview-support.jar file in the libs/ directory. Right click each JAR file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path.

Then most important
source code is in the java folder. To run this on eclipse, the fix was to right click on the java folder and select Build Path -> Use as Source Folder

Comment: Hii Pramod... I have register for Android wear devlopement preview ,But not got confirmation Mail.. Need Your Help...